# Error: Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an angular + firebase app and I have a service file that is supposed to fetch `members` from firebase realtime database:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "@angular/fire/database";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MembersService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  form = new FormGroup({        
    memberName: new FormControl(''),
    memberNumber: new FormControl(''),
    statusOn: new FormControl(false)
})

getMembers() { 

  let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data() }) )));
  return initialPayload;
}
```

However, I am getting an error inside the `getMembers()` method, in the following statement:

```js
key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data()
```

In both instances of `doc`, I get this error:
Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot'.
Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists'.ts(2339)

My packages versions are:

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5"

"firebase": "^8.6.7"
```

Comment: Try using the tap() operator in your pipe before using the map operator so you can see what you are working with while debugging: .pipe(tap(a => console.log(a)), map(...))

Comment: Alright, I did, and I have an array of snapshots in my console, as such: https://imgur.com/bWoUfmB
But I don't know what to do from here

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. It was probably because I was relying on a code related to Firebase Firestore, while I was actually using Firebase Realtime Database in my project.

The error I was getting because of `doc` was solved by simply removing it and using the correct variables, as such:

```js
let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.key, data: a.payload.val() }) ))) as Observable<any[]>
```