# How to specify the type of a var mid-statement

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I used to have this line in my code:

```js
let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges() as Observable<any[]>
```

Which changed to this line:

```js
let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data() }) )));
```

However, in the second line, I am getting an error:
Property 'doc' does not exist on type `DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>`

And I suspect that the solution to this error is to bring back the `as Observable<any[]>` from the initial code. But I don't know how to add it to the second line. Should it go like this (?):

```js
let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, data: a.payload.doc.data() }) ))) as Observable<any[]>
```

-?

If so, then my suspicions were wrong (because the error still persists after adding it at the end). But I need to make sure I've added it properly, so I would appreciate a confirmation of this.

Also since you've read this far, you're welcome to answer this question too:
[Error: Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914019/error-property-doc-does-not-exist-on-type-databasesnapshotunknown?noredirect=1#comment121793094_68914019)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. It had nothing to do with the types. It was probably because I was relying on a code related to firebase firestore, while I was actually using firebase reraltime database in my project.

The error I was getting because of `doc` was sovled by simply removing it and using the correct variables, as such:

```js
let initialPayload = this.db.list("/members").snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.key, data: a.payload.val() }) ))) as Observable<any[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `as` keyword which is similar to a cast. `a as T` would treat `a` as type `T`.